# In docker-compose, Error adding SSL Certificate to reverse proxy to consume websocket?

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, docker-compose, websocket

Deploying docker in `windows 11` and working with `docker-composer`, I am trying to enable the `ssl` certificate for my setup where I want to enable nginx as a reverse proxy to allow secure websockets `wss://` and for this to be redirected to my web server container, I show a Continuation of the files:

System structure:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Proxy-Server
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ${LH_CERTBOT}:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    ports:
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT:-443}:443"
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
      - "${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}:127.0.0.1"
    environment:
      - DEFAULT_HOST=${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=true
      - ENABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Proxy Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=reverse-proxy"
  certbot:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: SSL-Generator
    build:
      context: ./bin/certbot
    volumes:
      - ${LH_CERTBOT}:/etc/app/update-ssl.sh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    depends_on:
      - reverse-proxy
    networks:
      - lamp-network
  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_PHP_ENVIRONMENT}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ${LH_VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${LH_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2
      - ${LH_LOG_CRON}:/var/log/cron
    environment:
      LH_WEB_MASTER: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Web Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=webserver"
...
networks:
  lamp-network:
    name: lamp-network
    driver: bridge
```

in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM certbot/certbot

CMD chmod +x /etc/app/update-ssl.sh && ./etc/app/update-ssl.sh
```

***What I was hoping to do:***

my main idea is to set up certbot and share the interaction between containers once `certbot` has been completely started; execute the certificate generation using the file `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh` and restart the nginx service in the `reverse-proxy` container so that it reads and obtains the `ssl` certificate

***The Error I get:***
but even though the certbot container is assembled, it does not start and the log shows this error:

> 2023-09-25 16:09:10 usage:  2023-09-25 16:09:10   certbot [SUBCOMMAND]
> [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ... 2023-09-25 16:09:10  2023-09-25
> 16:09:10 Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.
> By default, 2023-09-25 16:09:10 it will attempt to use a webserver
> both for obtaining and installing the 2023-09-25 16:09:10 certificate.
> 2023-09-25 16:09:10 certbot: error: Unable to open config file: chmod
> +x /etc/app/update-ssl.sh && ./etc/app/update-ssl.sh. Error: No such file or directory

***Expectation:***
Although the errors are related to mounting and executing the file, fixing it does not guarantee that my script `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh` will do what I expect:

File `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Define variables
WEB_ROOT="${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}"

# Run Certbot to obtain the SSL certificate
certbot certonly --webroot --webroot-path="$WEB_ROOT" --email "${LH_WEB_MASTER}" --agree-tos -d "${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}" -d "${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}"

# Check if the certificate was obtained successfully
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Certificate obtained successfully. Restarting Nginx in the reverse-proxy container..."
  # Restart Nginx in the reverse-proxy container using Docker
  docker exec -it reverse-proxy service nginx restart
else
  echo "Certificate acquisition failed."
fi

# Start Certbot's renewal process in the background
certbot renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade &
# Keep the container running
exec "$@"
```

In short, I don't even know if what I'm doing will work or if I'm already doing the SSL certificate implementation wrong to begin with.

***Questions:***

1. <del>I am in the right way to get it working like expected? sug: yes/not</del>
2. <del>How do I solve the error of mounting the `.sh` file to run it from `CMD` (when the container starts up).</del>
3. <del>Although I have not yet tried the script file `/etc/app/update-ssl.sh` I would like it, it is not clear to me if it will fulfill the intention of restarting the nginx service in a separate container.</del>

***Final Objective:***
Enable websocket in a LAMP+reverse-proxy environment in docker, for the development of subsystems: chat, notifications and product inventory balance in real time.

***Context:***
Before making this publication I have tried to exhaust my research capacity and the publications on this site and the site in English, even other sites are not focused on covering the scenario that I present, therefore, the progress I have is a hybrid of several setups.

***--UPDATE--***

I have been investigating the issue and from the result I have apparently managed to install the certificate, at least I have not lost access via port 80, but now it gives me an error 500, which I cannot find in the error logs, to get to At this point I have updated the setup, the environment configuration code in `docker-compose.yaml` is no longer the same:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Proxy-Server
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    ports:
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${LH_HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT:-443}:443"
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    environment:
      - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=true
      - ENABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
    labels:
      com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    privileged: true

  nginx-ssl:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: SSL-Generator
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: Proxy-Server
      DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
    depends_on:
      - reverse-proxy
    networks:
      - lamp-network
  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-Web-Server
    build:
      context: ./bin/${LH_PHP_ENVIRONMENT}
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}:/var/www/html:rw
      - ${LH_PROJECT_ROOT}${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ${LH_VHOSTS_DIR}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${LH_LOG_DIR}:/var/log/apache2
      - ${LH_LOG_CRON}:/var/log/cron
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${LH_WEB_SERVER_DOMAIN}
      LH_WEB_MASTER: ${LH_WEB_MASTER}
      LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT: ${LH_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
      HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT: ${LH_HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${LH_MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=Web Server"
      - "lh2.setup.role=webserver"
...
  phpmyadmin:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: ${LH_SYSTEM_NAME}-phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: ${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: ${LH_PHPMYADMIN_DOMAIN}
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${LH_MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${LH_MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: ${LH_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
      MEMORY_LIMIT: ${LH_MEMORY_LIMIT}
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - ${LH_PHP_INI}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    labels:
      - "lh2.setup.description=phpMyAdmin"
      - "lh2.setup.role=phpmyadmin"
...
volumes:
  vhost:
  html:
  certs:
  acme:
  conf:
  dhparam:
networks:
  lamp-network:
    name: lamp-network
    driver: bridge
```

## Actual context:

What I am trying is to be able to anchor the communication between the reverse-proxy and the webserver and phpmyamin container via docker's intranet... implementing `VIRTUAL_HOST`, what I do believe is that the container that runs Apache, despite having the port 443 open the apache is not configured to do anything with it, I have added the configuration of that virtual host to this post previously, remember that I am doing all this from the `YAML` file, I am looking for a way to avoid the terminal.. .for installation automation reasons, now all this revolves around websocket consumption; I don't see a way to anchor the SSL certificate to both the proxy and the web server, I thought the idea was to consume the SSL only with the proxy and for it to communicate only through port 80 to consume the containers... but my mistake now What I am paying for is wanting to also consume port 443 of the web server container, therefore also that of phpmyadmin... and to create compatibility with a future production environment if they are implementing it.